# WMP player doesn't play mp3 file. no errors

Tags: c#, wmplib

I've been trying to play mp3 player with MS VS 2015 for a long time. Firstly, had error about unknow library, fixed that with adding reference to wmp.dll. Then no errors, however file still doesn't play. Added reference to COM WMP still no sound. I don't know what to do, did a lot of research in this topic, nothing helps.

```
    static WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.URL = "C:\\Gangster.mp3";
        wplayer.controls.play();
    }
```

Comment: WMP is an ActiveX component.  Like all such components, it expects to be used on the UI thread of a GUI program.  Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms, apply the [STAThread] attribute to Main() and append System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();  And now you made it happy and it works.  Just use the correct project template to start your project.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you very, very much! You saved me tons of time

Comment: @HansPassant please don't answer the question in a comment.